# contents of UIText View does not render while "off screen" on iOS device

Tags: ios, xcode, uitextview

I am using a UITextView to render some text. I am using the following code to render my main view larger, to set the output higher res ( I also scale all the sub-views by the same factor ).

```
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(ImageView.frame.size.width*4, ImageView.frame.size.height*4));
[outputView setFrame:CGRectMake(outputView.frame.origin.x, outputView.frame.origin.y, outputView.frame.size.width*4, outputView.frame.size.height*4)];
     [[outputView layer] renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
```

Works fine in terms of scaling. The only issue is that the UITextView element will not render properly if it is "off sccreen". So everything renders fine without the *4 scale factor, but with it the UITextView elements that are pushed off screen are not rendered properly (mostly just blank).

Is there a way to override this, to force it to render?

Thanks for reading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up using labels, just for rendering. So the UIText views are used to display in the interface, and for interaction, but they are temporarily hidden and replaced by labels for rendering.

Comment: Thank you so much - I was struggling with this for hours and this solved it for me!

Answer (score 2):

Do this:

```
  CGAffineTransform newtransform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(4.0, 4.0);
  self.view.transform = newtransform;
  CGRect newFrame = CGRectApplyAffineTransform(self.view.frame, newtransform);
  //CGSize fittingSize = [yourTextView sizeThatFits:CGSizeZero];
  UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newFrame.size);
  [self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
  UIImahe *capImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
  UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Comment: Thanks. I am not having any trouble outputting a perfect image of my entire parent view which happens to contain any number of UIText Views and UIimage view. The problem is after scaling the view as described above. Not sure if there is a fix in your code, but thnaks anyway and let me know if I missed it.

Answer (score 0):

To build on Mrwolfy's answer, I also managed to solve a similar problem by copying the contents of the `UITextView` in to a `UILabel` - it seems to behaves somewhat differently for whatever reason. Here's the code I used:

```
UILabel* contents = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:textView.frame];
[textView.superview addSubview:contents];
contents.numberOfLines = 0;
contents.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
contents.attributedText = textView.attributedText;

textView.hidden = YES;

// Now render the scrollview in slices
for (CGFloat y = 0; y < scrollView.contentSize.height; y += scrollView.frame.size.height) {
    [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, y) animated:NO];
    [scrollView.layer renderInContext:context];
}

textView.hidden = NO;

[contents removeFromSuperview];
```